# Como ordenar los nombres de contactos alfabéticamente incluyendo los que contienen tilde

Tags: java, android, ordenamiento

Tengo un pequeño problema. Realice una función en android studio que me muestra los nombres y números de teléfono de la agenda:

```
 protected void CargarLista(Cursor c) {

    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        try {
            HashSet<String> normalizedNumbersAlReady = new HashSet<>();
            int normalizedNumber = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER);
            int DisplayName = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int DisplayNumber = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            int DisplayType = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);


            while (c.moveToNext()){
                String normalized = c.getString(normalizedNumber);
                if (normalizedNumbersAlReady.add(normalized)) {
                    String nombre = c.getString(DisplayName);
                    String telefono = c.getString(DisplayNumber);
                    String tipo = c.getString(DisplayType);
                    String sType = "";
                    switch (tipo) {
                        case "0":
                            sType = "Otro";
                            break;
                        case "1":
                            sType = "Casa";
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            sType = "Movil";
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            sType = "Trabajo";


                    }


                    postArrayList.add(new Item_contactos(nombre, telefono, sType));
                }


                myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(postArrayList,Contactos.this);
                listView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
            }


        }finally {
            c.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Estos están ordenados de forma ascendente por medio del cursor:

```
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

El problema aparece al tener nombres que poseen tildes, ya que aparecen siempre al final de la lista. Alguien me podría orientar con esto? Necesito que se ordenen como corresponde independiente de su tilde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás utilizando ArrayList<> para agrupar podés utilizar el método sort(). Te dejo un ejemplo que te recomiendo que pruebes creando una aparte como prueba **Clase** que se llame **Test1**, **copiá el código que te voy a pasar**, y dale a "Run as java application" (Si utilizas Eclipse), finalmente **analizá** si te sirve esta implementación en tu proyecto.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Mariano");
        list.add("Gerardo");
        list.add("Ines");
        list.add("Charly");
        list.add("Ernesto");
        list.add("Estella");
        list.add("Alberto");
        Collections.sort(list);

        for (String item : list) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }

    }

}
```

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mirando un poco **tu código** no encuentro **dónde se instancia** el ArrayList<> **postArrayList**, por lo cual imagino que está dentro de la clase y a su vez fuera del método en cuestión, si es así, te recomiendo que sólo copies esta linea **Collections.sort(postArrayList);** adentro del método en cuestión y fuera del **while**.

Si el problema exacto es el tema de los acentos al principio el siguiente código te puede ayudar, utilizando la Clase **Collator** que actúa como **comparadora de candenas**.

**Tomamos como base el ejemplo anterior pero con acentos:**

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Mariano");
        list.add("Gerardo");
        list.add("Ines");
        list.add("Charly");
        list.add("Ernesto");
        list.add("Estella");
        list.add("Ésteban");
        list.add("Álberto");

        ArrayList<String> listNew = organizedAlphabeticList(list);
        for (String item : listNew) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }

    }

    public static ArrayList<String> organizedAlphabeticList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();

            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return collator.compare(o1, o2);
            }
        });
        return list;
    }

}
```

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El funcionamiento interno de este código no lo sé, sólo sé que se puede configurar para que dependiendo el lenguaje actúe de una u otra manera, sin embargo cómo funciona esta Clase Collator que implementa el método compare() no te lo puedo explicar porque no la sé. Seguramente la explicación esté dentro la doc oficial Oracle, ya que esta clase viene dentro de las JDK.

Lo seguro es que éste código puede ser adaptado a tus necesidades, sólo tendrás que probar un poco más, ya estás cerca. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: luego de entenderlo, funciono sin problema. Muchas gracias!